# key product fail does affect on mailto in html

Tags: html

Iam use mailto to send email. However it seems doesn't work, i don't know why

```
<a href="mailto:myemail">contact</a>
```

By the way my microsoft office is key failure. Is that a problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `mailto` in a link-href should work without any problems. Just use a valid email-address and have a mail-program configured to accept those mailto-calls.

```
<a href="mailto:foo@bar.com">Send me a mail</a>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/mS9yh/ for a working demo.